# Lightweight website : using lazy loading and anchor

Tags: html, lazy-loading, anchor

I'm trying to make a lightweight website using no (or just a little) of JavaScript. So just HTML and CSS.

I'm working on a page where I'm summarizing images and when we click on that image it scrolls to the end of the summary where I display every image on large scale and explain what it's about.

So everything is working with a href to an anchor but the problem is that since I want to make the website as light as possible, I'm using `loading=lazy` on my images but the href anchor trigger every loading on the way...

Is there a way to use both href anchor and lazy loading without JavaScript (or in a lightweight version)?

Comment: Maybe I can hide all the "large scall" version and add a class that display it when we click on the image

Comment: I did that but it was not possible to display le large scroll with url. 
So I added a test for "#" in the url at the loading of the page, if it find it I call my function to display the large version and ``document.getElementById(document.URL.slice(document.URL.indexOf("#")+1).scrollIntoView()`` to scroll to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in css trigger the loading of every image on the way

So if I don't that use that transition I don't have to put JS on that page !

But if it's something you really want, you can hide divs with large images and write a simple function to display it when you click on the thumb.